# How to prevent JSoup from relocating inline styles?

Tags: jsoup

I'm facing a problem where JSoup moves inline styles to the head tag. E.g. the following content:

```
<style>.foo { background: url(/path1/img.jpg); }</style>
```

after parsing gets converted into the below document:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>.foo { background: url(/path1/img.jpg); }</style>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

This relocation breaks apps logic dealing with processing of non standard tags inside the style tag. I assume, the same relocation will happen to inline script tags.

Is there a way to disable this relocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use HTML4, the `<style>` tag is supposed to be in the `<head>` tag, but will still work. Check the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html), as it is generally bad practice to put it elsewhere. If you use HTML5, you can use the `<style scoped>` tag which allows you to put it anywhere you want in your body.

If you aren't the owner of the source code, the below solution will work for you.

You can use the Jsoup XmlParser instead of the regular HtmlParser, which will parse the document without any knowledge of the tags, and instead parse it as is.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

will render your `Document` html just as the source is.